# PHP Excel download - Downloaded file looks has garbage

Tags: php

When I try to download a file (not displaying it in the browser) the file opens but looks corrupted. But when I save the file in the server and open it later the file has the contents. This code works in windows. But I have the problem only when I move this to linux. The code I am using is as below.

```
if (strtoupper(GST_EXCEL_FILE_FORMAT) == "XLS") {
        $filename = DOL_DOCUMENT_ROOT."/gst/template/GSTR1_Excel_Workbook_Template-V1.5.xls";
    }
    elseif  (strtoupper(GST_EXCEL_FILE_FORMAT) == "XLSX")
    {
        $filename = DOL_DOCUMENT_ROOT."/gst/template/GSTR1_Excel_Workbook_Template-V1.5.xlsx";
    }

    $fileextension= pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($filename);

    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

    $objReader->setLoadAllSheets();
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filename);


    $ii= 8;

    $row = 5; // 1-based index

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName("b2b");  //set first sheet as active

    $objectLines = $resultset[0];

    foreach ($objectLines as $line)
    {
        $col = 0;
        {

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow( $col, $row, $line->gstin);
            $col++;
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $line->invoiceno);
            $col++;
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $line->invoicedate);
            $col++;
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $line->totalvalue);
            $col++;
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $line->pos);
            $col++;
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $line->reverse_flag);
            $col++;
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $line->invoice_type);
            $col++;
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $line->ecommgst);
            $col++;
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $line->Rate);
            $col++;
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $line->Taxable_value);
            $col++;
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $line->Cess);
        }
        $row++;
    }

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $inputFileType);

    $outputfilename=mt_rand(1,100000).".".$fileextension; 
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$outputfilename.'"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');


    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Did you tried debug $filename?

Comment: Make certain that absolutely nothing besides the file stream is being output to the browser.... open it in a text editor. look for leading/trailing whitespace characters, BOM headers, html markup, plaintext PHP errors, etc